# Instagram CDN Not working with Safari

Tags: api, safari, instagram, cdn

I am using the instagram API to make a web app.  The app works in every browser except for safari.

Instagram stores most of their pictures in 2 different CDNs: scontent, or igcdn.  The photos load correctly for igcdn, but not scontent, see the sample links below:

https://igcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t51.2885-19/10693616_737229973060787_1464183967_a.jpg

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xta1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12093273_724561414354004_1362372351_n.jpg

The first photo (igcdn) works in all browsers that I've tested.  But, the second one (scontent.cdn) doesn't work in safari, which causes my whole app to break. I don't know if this is safari's fault or instagram--does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Both photos loaded for me on Safari 5.1.7 running on Window 8. Can you check DNS caching?

Comment: Thank you for checking.  I tried loading the pictures today, and they're now working--I've never heard of DNS caching, but it sounds like it could've been the reason.  I still have a major problem with my app specific to only safari (involving access token) but at least this problem is now solved.  Thanks again.